# How can I trace a crash in a program that crashes X?

Tags: xorg, skype

Skype is crashing my entire X server, and the bug I reported (since fixed) is no longer relevant, nor useful. I've found an alternate client, but now someone wants to use rooms (and it's imperative), so I need to get this fixed. What should I do to trace where the crash is coming from? It crashes the Xserver, so basically, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant component you need to trace is X, not the application causing the crash.

There is some detailed information at the Ubuntu wiki:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where Skype, Spotify, Qbittorrent, and Glogg would crash the X server.
I noticed that all these apps use Qt4.

Then I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/927288) solution.
Comment out the following lines from /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Files"
FontPath "unix/:7100"
EndSection
```

Now log out and log back in.